# loop results or big array?

Tags: php, mysql

Just curious how any of you who approch this problem.

I have some rows I retrieve and per row I have 10 images. What would be the best way to retrieve these records with images?

I have two approaches:
- select the rows, loop them and per row get the images.
- select the rows, extract the id's. Get all images by id, keyed array and loop and stick them to their specific row.

The second approach is just two queries but more work on the PHP side. What is the best method, or is there a better way?

Comment: DBMS are *always* "better" and "optimized" than user PHP code (looking to performance of course!). My personal approach: if query is well written, tables are dell indexed, use DB query. Otherwise make some benchmark tests :)

Comment: Just do a benchmark for both ways! For me reading the whole result set in PHP should be faster.